# Google map marker loop only showing first iteration

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I've used the code from this: http://jsfiddle.net/ErYub/

But changed it to pull records from my database:

```
#{ 
(Datacentre.find(:all, :conditions => "longitude != false").map do |d|

"var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(#{d.latitude}, #{d.longitude})
   marker#{d.id} = new MarkerWithLabel({
     position: latLng,
     draggable: false,
     map: map,
     icon: {url:'/assets/icon_red.png'}

   });

    markers.push(marker#{d.id});

  makeDiv(#{d.id}, 15, 'Marker #');
   google.maps.event.addListener(markers[#{d.id}], 'click', function(e) {
  infowindow.setContent('Marker postion: '  + this.getPosition());
  infowindow.open(map, this);});

"end).join

}


  var clusterOptions = { zoomOnClick: false }
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);
  globalMarker = markers.slice();
  google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
  var content = '';

var info = new google.maps.MVCObject;
info.set('position', cluster.center_);


var markers = cluster.getMarkers();

var titles = "";
#{ 
(Datacentre.find(:all, :conditions => "longitude != false AND reference != ''").map do |d|

"titles = markers[#{d.id}].labelContent + "\n";
"end).join

}
```

the code that is shown in the browser looks how i'd expect it to, yet only the first marker is show and the info box doesn't appear.

Generated Code

```
function initialize() {
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(45.4214, -75.6919);
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 3,
center: center,
disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var markers = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.72385, -1.90664)
marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
position: latLng,
draggable: false,
map: map,
icon: {url:'/assets/icon_red.png'}
});
markers.push(marker1);
makeDiv(1, 15, 'Marker #');
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[1], 'click', function(e) {
infowindow.setContent('Marker postion: ' + this.getPosition());
infowindow.open(map, this);});
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.04062, -0.75942)
marker6 = new MarkerWithLabel({
position: latLng,
draggable: false,
map: map,
icon: {url:'/assets/icon_red.png'}
});
markers.push(marker6);
makeDiv(6, 15, 'Marker #');
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[6], 'click', function(e) {
infowindow.setContent('Marker postion: ' + this.getPosition());
infowindow.open(map, this);}); 

ETC

var titles = "";
;
;
;
;
;
;
;
;
;
```

Comment: Can you add the generated JS?

Answer (score 1):

Error i think is in this line(here is an error)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[1], 'click', function(e) {
 //markers[0] contains the marker. not markers[1]
 //the same applies in place of markers[6] also. it is markers[1]
```